# multi-select checkboxes for categories in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a newbie to rails and I have a Lesson model and a Category model. I also have subcategories and am using ancestry to handle that. What I'd like to do is when I create a new lesson or go to edit an existing lesson, I'd like to list the categories with the subcategories indented, but all with checkboxes so I can assign multiple categories to each lesson.

In my Lesson model, I have:
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

Do I need to do anything in the Category model?

In my form, I know it's not listing the categories in an ancestry format, but my attempt to at least getting the categories to show

```
<% Category.all.each do |cat| %>
            <%= check_box_tag "lesson.[category_ids][]", cat.id, @lesson.category_ids.include?(cat.id) %>
        <% end %>
```

I get a bunch of checkboxes, but no categories and I get an error on the edit page: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: categories_lessons: SELECT "categories".id FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_lessons" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_lessons"."category_id" WHERE "categories_lessons"."lesson_id" = ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A checkbox tag literally just puts the checkbox... if you want writing beside each checkbox... you have to add writing too :) eg `<%= @cat.description %>` (or whatever you've actually called the appropriate column)

Comment: The app seems to miss the middle table between Category and Lesson. Do you have  has_and_belongs_to_many :lessons in category model?

Comment: And you have extra "."  in "lesson.[category_ids][]" in the question. How about using [collection_check_boxes](http://www.webdeveloperfromscratch.com/blog/rails-code-check_box_tag-vs-collection_check_boxes)?

Comment: @TarynEast... lol... good catch

Comment: I followed the suggestions. I can get it to work when creating a new lesson (the categories show with the checkboxes), but when I go to edit an existing Lesson, I get the 'no such table: categories_lessons: SELECT "categories".id FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_lessons" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_lessons"."category_id" WHERE "categories_lessons"."lesson_id" = ?' error. Any ideas?